# Code only runs in console

Tags: javascript

My code seems to run only in the console, however... This code is deployed after the page loads. (You manually load it.. Bookmarks..)
Yet when I put in the browser...
javascript:(code stuff here)
nothing happens. If I go to the console then it broadcasts the alert. (testing purposes)

```
function addServer() {
if (localStorage.server1 == 0) {
alert("moo");
} else {

}



}

function removeServer() {

}


// Detect if on server page or not... Server page has id tabs. List does not.

localStorage.setItem("server1", "0")
addServer();
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try removing the comment (it's probably commenting out all the lines after it since the whole code is running on one line) and adding semicolons after the function declarations:

```
function addServer() {
if (localStorage.server1 == 0) {
alert("moo");
} else {

}



};

function removeServer() {

};



localStorage.setItem("server1", "0");
addServer();
```

Comment: Thank you so much! (I can't accept a answer unless it's in 8 minutes..)

Comment: No problem - glad to help!